# want to know if const char* ptr leads to any memory leak,

Tags: c++14

I am new to C++ coding and want to know if i am using a `const char* ptr` and and doing a step, will there be any memory leak. If yes, how to tackle that? I cannot show the exact code but the outline is

```
char letter[];
const char* lettrptr= *somefunc(argument)*;
strcpy(letter,lettrptr);
```

The whole code is woking fine. But my doubt is will there be any memory leak for `const char* ptr` and if yes how to solve that?

Comment: Do you do a `delete` at the end of your function call ?

Comment: I am not doing any delete in the end, I was thinking of using free but I guess free does not work

Answer (score 1):

A memory leak doesn't come from using `const char *`, or any other type.

A memory leak comes from not freeing the memory after it is no longer needed.

In your case, you have the function `somefunc`. It is either written by you of by someone else. Anyway, you have to find out whether the function expects the caller to free the memory or not.

Because of the `const`, it is very likely that the function doesn't expect you to free the memory, but to be safe you should check anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Does `somefunc()` allocate memory for the string? Or does it return a pointer to something statically allocated?

In the first case, `somefunc()` will return the result of a call to `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or some similar function). If this is the case, that memory can be leaked, so you will need to `free()` it.

In the second case, `somefunc()` will return a `char*` that is either a global, or a local static like one of the following:

```
char global_str[] = "Hello";

const char *somefuncA()
{
  return global_str;
}

const char *somefuncB()
{
  static char static_str[] = "World";
  return static_str;
}
```

If one of these is the case, the memory will not leak (and you must NOT try to `free()` it).